# How to pass input values to an executable file from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, subprocess

I have been working on a code using subprocess to grab some data from a CSV file and pass it on as input to an executable file. The exe file if tried to open normally asks for a bunch of input values that have been compiled in the CSV file.

I can open the exe file using my current program but the input values from the CSV are not getting passed on the executable. Let me know in case anyone has any leads on the same:

```
import subprocess
with open(r'C:\Users\NH.csv') as f:
     read_data = f.read()

subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\NGP.exe',read_data],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Also, find the view of the exe file as it asks for the input values:

[image: EXE Program Screenshot]

Moreover the [sample input CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbxZG.png) is provided

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the whole content of the file as a single argument to the executable?

Comment: @gshpychka. Actually I thought of using the CSV input to reduce the task of reducing multiple inputs. Let me know in case you have any better ideas. The program sequentially takes around 25 input arguments.

Comment: `read_data` is a single string that contains the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Unclear what "the program sequentially takes" input arguments means. All 25 arguments will have to be passed when creating the `subprocess.Popen` if it means from the command line, otherwise you will have to pipe them in one at a time if the executable is expecting them to read them from `stdin`.

Comment: @martineau Sorry for the miscommunication there. As you can see in the image the program is asking for 2 inputs. Once these 2 inputs are passed on, the file asks for another set of input values and so on...total of 25 inputs are needed to actually completely run the executable.

Comment: That's certainly not obvious from the screenshot. Anyway, you will need to pipe the values it's asking for by specifying the `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` keyword argument when creating the `Popen` instance, and then using the `Popen.communicate()` method to send the data it's expecting through the pipe. You can get that data for a CSV file, a plain text file, or somewhere else. Getting it from a CSV file would depend on the data layout of the file.

Comment: @martineau. Thanks a lot for your help regarding the use of Popen and to pipe the inputs using Popen.communicate(). However, while passing the inputs, I am getting the error as " 'bytes' type object is required instead of list'. I think the data from the CSV is captured as a single string rather than the individual numbers. Do you think there is a way to convert this list to bytes or if i can follow a different approach to pipe my data.

Comment: What you think is correct. The way you are getting the data in the file is as one long string, which you would need to encode into bytes using something like: `read_data.encode('utf-8')` to avoid that problem. Note however that you will probably also need to break the string up in separate items separated by a newlines, depending on exactly how the EXE reads data from its `stdin` *and* the format of the data in the CSV — which you still haven't specified.

Comment: @martineau. Thanks for your inputs. For better clarification, I have added the sample input CSV file in the question itself.

Comment: After encoding the bytes into a string, you can try using that as `stdin`. If you need to break it up you can use `lines = read_data.splitlines(True)` to convert it into a list of strings each with a newline at the end.

Comment: @martineau. Thanks a lot. The code works totally fine now.